# Formatting datetime variable

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to convert and store a date in the form of String into datetime variable.

```
String fromdate= "02-JUN-2014";
DateTime dFromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(fromdate);
```

This dfromDate  is used in another function which expects date to be in 02-JUN-2014 format.But since dfromDate storing the date as 06/02/2014, there is a format exception.

Comment: for starters without wrapping the string around double quotes `" "` this would never compile. so I am not sure how you are getting `01/02/2014` as a value. using this code returns a valid date 
`String fromdate = "02 - JUN - 2014";
 DateTime dFromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(fromdate);`

Comment: What do yo mean by this _but it is getting stored as 01/02/2014 which is causing format exception_ exactly? You successfully parse your `string` to `DateTime` and see your `dFromDate` as `01/02/2014` in a debugger or your `fromdate` is _actually_ `01/02/2014`?

Comment: @SonerGönül I run the code wrapping the string value around quotes and it returns a valid datetime not sure how the OP can claim that they are getting `01/02/2014` unless there is somewhere else in their code where they are trying to convert the incorrect date.. I would suggest that the OP start using the Debugger and setting break points as well !

Comment: Sorry for mistakes in the question, have corrected them now. Glad people understood and gave required answer. @SonerGönül it is shown in the debugger as 06/02/2014 but even after using parseexact, the debugger shows it sameway but the exception is removed.

Comment: @MethodMan Yeah, OP updated to `01/02/2014` to `06/02/2014` but still this _getting stored as 06/02/2014_ seems weird because based on selected answer, OP does not _even_ store it because of `FormatException`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ParseExact()`

```
String fromdate="02-JUN-2014";
DateTime dFromDate = DateTime.ParseExact(fromdate, "dd-MMM-yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: This won't compile though. ;)

Comment: @rinukkusu hope it will now :)

Comment: @Habib ya correct..edited accordingly

Comment: @Habib I don't think `-` will effect the current culture's `DateSeparator`. As far as I know, there is only [The `/` character](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator) _can_ behave differently. Since you know, `InvariantCulture` has `/` as a `DateSeparator` and this code won't throw any exception at all :)

Comment: @SonerGönül, you are right, I have to find a better example.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap fromDate in quotes:

```
var fromdate = "02-JUN-2014";
var dFromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(fromdate);
```

Comment: Since OP gets `FormatException`, I think OP's code _already_ compile successfully. Just `Convert.ToDateTime` can't parse this string. You are right, OP didn't write [MCVE] but forgetting double quotes doesn't seems a case here.

Answer (score 0):

I am not to sure of the entire context but you could always use the folowing to create a new date:

```
DateTime thisDate1 = new DateTime(2011, 6, 10);
Console.WriteLine("Today is " + thisDate1.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy") + ".");

// The example displays the following output:
//    Today is June 10, 2011.
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. OP can't parse string to DateTime, not vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

```
String fromdate= "02-JUN-2014";
DateTime dFromDate = DateTime.ParseExact(fromdate,"dd-MMM-yyyy", 
                                         CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Use `ParseExact` method.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `DateTime.ParseExact` i.e.

```
DateTime dFromDate = DateTime.ParseExact(fromdate, "dd-MMM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You may need to specific a culture for your language if you are not US (CultureInfo.InvariantCulture is a special form of US).

Answer (score 0):

`Convert.ToDateTime` uses standard date and time format of your [`CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture) and looks like `dd-MMM-yyyy` is not one of them.

You can use [`ParseExact` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact) with *english-based* culture like [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture).

```
String fromdate = "02-JUN-2014";
DateTime dFromDate = DateTime.ParseExact(fromdate, "dd-MMM-yyyy", 
                                         CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `DateTime.ParseExact`might work, and itis the best option if you know exactly the format string, but you could also set the current `CultureInfo` for the call:

```
String fromdate= "02-JUN-2014";
DateTime dFromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(fromdate, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Or:

```
String fromdate= "02-JUN-2014";
DateTime dFromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(fromdate, new CultureInfo("es-ES"));
```

Comment: Be aware, OP's `CurrentCulture` _might_ not be english-based one. In such a case, this method can't parse `JUN` part.

Answer (score -1):

Your first problem might be, that you need to assign a string like this:

```
String fromdate = "02-JUN-2014";
```

Comment: it returns the correct datetime as with the spaces running the code wrapping the `" "` around the string date value returns `{6/2/2014 12:00:00 AM}`